# Recursive self join in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, self-join

I have the following table:

```
| node_id | node_name | parent_id |  
| 1       | Node 1    |           |  
| 2       | Node 2    | 1         |  
| 3       | Node 3    | 1         |  
| 4       | Node 4    | 2         |
```

I want to retrieve recursively all the nodes under a specific node.

My model looks like this:

```
class Tree extends Model
{
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'node_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id', 'node_id');
    }

    public function allchildren()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id', 'node_id')->with('allchildren');;
    }
}
```

Now if I want to retrieve all descendants of a node, I do the following:

```
$node = Tree::where('node_id', 1)->first();
$nodes = $node->allchildren;
```

However the above code is returning only the first level and ignoring deeper levels of children.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit**

As a matter of fact, I understand now that I am actually retrieving all the data properly, it's just I'm seeing the top level of the output array.

The question would be how can I flatten the output to show me the data in a single array?

**Edit 2**

So I managed to create a function to flat the output into a one-level array using the following code (in the controller for example):

```
public function flattenTree($array)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        $result[] = ['node_id'=>$item['node_id'], 'node_name'=>$item['node_name']];
        $result = array_merge($result, $this->flattenTree($item['allchildren']));
    }
    return array_filter($result);
}
```

and then call it this way:

```
$flatTree = $this->flattenTree($nodes);
```

Comment: `with` will execute a `select if exists` once. It is not a recursive operation. You could look at performing some logic on the children collection to get all nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) using `with()`. So it'd look like

```
Tree::where('node_id', 1)->with('allchildren')->get();
```

You could go nested eager loading as well.

```
Tree::where('node_id', 1)->with('children.children')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, this actually works, but how can I flatten the output of the output?

Comment: @Lamar I'm glad :) Since it returns an Eloquent collection, so you can use [collection methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#available-methods) to further manipulate your output. There's a [flatten()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-flatten) method, but I'm not sure if it's going to be helpful since your node could have many children, so depending on your expected output, you might have to use [mappings](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-flatmap) or other [iterative](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-each) methods.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I think you could achieve this with something like this.

```
public function allChildren()
{
    $nodes = collect();
    $this->children->each(function($node) use ($nodes){
      $nodes->push($node);
      $nodes = $nodes->merge($node->allChildren()); //merge this node's children
    });
    return $nodes;
}
```

The logic basically is to call `allChildren` for each of the `children` and make a new collection of nodes. Downside of this particular logic is that it will get all nodes in a single level collection.

Comment: Actually what I need is to get all the children in one level. Basically similar to the table structure. But what does this line mean:  `$nodes = collect();`

Comment: That is opening a new empty collection. Did you test this code?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Laravel. So you mean I should replace my relation with this method, or is this a helper method to flatten the output or my relation?

Comment: you can use this in place of the `allchildren` method in the model, or put it the model as a new method and if you are happy with the outcome you can use this.

Comment: It's not working. Not sure how to call this method, whether as a relation attribute, an abstract method, or should I pass the parent node as argument?

Comment: oh, i was thinking about attaching this to an already retrieved node. I can look into getting this with the initial get. A bit busy right now.